# Is there any possible way to solve $m\ddot{x} + kx +\mu mg =0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any possible way to solve this .Here $\dot x = dx/dt$ t is time here, Ive tried many online calculators . My own known methods don't seem ti work (like e^{rt} method;  cf pi method; wronskian method nothing seems to work.  $m\ddot{x} + kx +\mu mg =0$ and yeah x is the only variable here. $\dot x = v$ when t=0 x= 0.

Comment: $m$,$k$,$\mu$,$g$ depend on $t$ or are constant? Check this, https://www.math24.net/second-order-linear-homogeneous-differential-equations-constant-coefficients/

Comment: @Hans x is the only variable means anything else in the equation is constant.  Should I specify that in the question?

Comment: This is a [driven harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Driven_harmonic_oscillators) with constant driving force $F(t)  = -\mu mg$. The general solution is the solutions to the homogenous equation $m\ddot{x} + kx = 0$ plus the particular solution $x_p = -\mu m g /k$

Comment: @Winther the only problem is $\mu mg $ does not depend on t. If it had x in it then ill probably be able to solve it.

Comment: Why is that a problem? In fact it does depend on $t$. It's a constant, which is the simplest time dependence you can have.

Comment: @Winther so should i solve the equation in two parts ie $m\ddot x = - kx$ which would lead to sin and cos functions. And anther part as $m\ddot x= \mu mg$ and then add both of them .

Comment: Intuitively this is simple harmonic motion, but with a central value shifted away from $0$, not much different from a vertical spring under gravity

Comment: It's not really to solve $m\ddot{x} = \mu mg$. The usual way of finding a particular solution is to try an ansatz on the same form as your driving force (with some free parameters to fit). If it's a constant try a constant. If it's an exponential try an exponential, etc. If you plug in $x(t) = C$ then the ODE gives you $kC + \mu mg = 0$ which has a solution. If this didn't work then you had to modify your guess and try again.

Comment: @Winther thanks for the help.  Got a new way to solve a differential equation.

Comment: This is a very classical undamped oscillator with a constant excitation. How come that you cannot solve ? The $e^{rt}$ method does work.

Comment: @YvesDaoust well then lets put $x= e^{rt}$ $mr^2 +kr + \mu mg e^{-rt} =0$ now can you solve for r???

Comment: No, the method is applied on the homogeneous part of the equation. Then you look for a particular solution of the non-homogenous equation (a constant will do).

Comment: @YvesDaoust well i have to admit i didn't know the constant part. The first can be solved easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve first $$m\ddot{x} + kx=0$$Let's call the solution for this $x_h(t)$. Then just add a constant $C$ to it. Plug it into the original equation. The derivative of a constant is null. $$m\ddot{x}_h + kx_h+kC+\mu mg=0$$
The sum of the first two terms is zero, so $$C=-\frac{\mu m g}k$$
The final answer is $$x(t)=A\sin\omega t+B\cos\omega t-\frac{\mu m g}k$$with $\omega^2=k/m$

Answer (score 0):

With bare hands:

$$\ddot{x} + \frac kmx +\mu g =0,$$

$$\dot x\ddot{x} + \frac kmx\dot x +\mu g \dot x=0,$$
$$\dot x^2 + \frac kmx^2 +2\mu g x=c,$$

$$\frac{\dot x}{\sqrt{c-2\mu gx-\dfrac kmx^2}}=0.$$

Now by a linear transformation applied to $x$, you can reduce to a form

$$\frac{\dot z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}=0$$ or $$\arcsin z=+d$$ or $$ax+b=\sin(d)$$ where $a,b$ are known.

Comment: @user187604: multiplied.

Comment: @user187604: how is *what* possible ?

Comment: @user187604: can you pinpoint anything wrong in this development ?

Comment: @user187604: notice that my answer is the same as the one you accepted.

Comment: @user187604: integration.

Comment: @yvesdauost why did you accept "How did you insert $x=\dot x$?" I was thinking you have done this instead of integration.  Really sorry . Your solution is perfectly fine. Well great idea though.

Comment: in your fourth line it had been 1 instead of c in the right side.

Comment: you may delete your previous comments.